# Is data.to_json.html_safe susceptible to XSS attack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, xss

I'm trying to figure out if this code is safe.
Is it at all possible to attack this code?

```
<script>
  data = <%= data.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

In other words, what value of `data` would result in a successful attack?

Answer (score -1):

It kind of depends on what you are doing with the data and the version of Rails you are using. If you are using anything past Rails 3 then no, calling `html_safe` could make your code vulnerable to XSS.

Basically, what you are doing is telling the app that `data.to_json` is html safe. However, the application doesn't actually know that for sure.

What `html_safe` does is it marks a string as safe to be inserted directly into HTML without escaping anything within the string. As described in the method api, it should never be used on user input. Constructed input may be safe, but it is up to you to ensure that it is.

`to_json` converts a given string into JSON. By default, it does not escape HTML characters like `<, / >`

Thus, if `data` is user input, it is entirely possible for someone to insert their own script into it and have it marked as safe (and thus rendered as html) the way it is currently written.

The way this is written, if someone does the following:

`data = "</script><script>insert_xss_attack_here</script>"`

Your code will not escape the script, resulting in the script being executed by the code.

Many people have described the issues with html_safe and to_json:

This deals specifically with to_json.html_safe
http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/

https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/you-never-want-to-call-html_safe-in-a-rails-template/

http://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong

Comment: Thanks for the links, but your answer is ambiguous, could you make it more clear?

Comment: "`to_json` converts a given string into JSON. By default, it does not escape HTML characters like `<, / >`." This is true of the default JSON library, but it's not true of recent versions of Rails. With Rails 6.0.3.4, I ran `rails new test_app; cd test_app; rails c; '<>'.to_json`, and the output was `"\u003c\u003e"`.